# ASP.NET MVC - custom membership

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I attach a custom membership provider in my ASP.NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655383/how-can-i-attach-a-custom-membership-provider-in-my-asp-net-mvc-application)

In ASP.NET MVC4 you can add attributes to your controllers/actions that restrict access to authenticated users or users that belong to certain roles.

I want to utilize this a project I'm working on, but I would rather not have to work with .NET Membership Provider.  I would prefer to create my own database structure to keep track of users and roles and so forth.

What do I need to do in order to utilize the authentication attributes with my own custom membership implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this? It provides a method of doing this: http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/

Answer (score 0):

> What do I need to do in order to utilize the authentication attributes with my own custom membership implementation

They aren't *authentication* attributes, they're *authorization* attributes.

To use them with your own roles, the easiest solution is to implement a [custom RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx), in which case the `Authorize` attribute should work automatically.