# Basic Login / Authorization in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two Controllers in my MVC4 application that I want to require users to be logged into to access; an 'admin' area of sorts.

I have a database linked class that handles authentication for me in C#, meaning I can do something like this:

```
LoginUtility lu = new LoginUtility();
if(lu.Login("username", "password") == true){
   // User is genuine
} else {
   // Login failed
}
```

I want to hook this up to MVC4 so I can apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to those two Controllers.

Comment: Does MVC4 not provide with such an authentication feature, even allowing you to take advantage of the OpenAuth of this world?

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found doing custom login logic quite the pain. What you need to do is extend `AuthorizeAttribute` so you can use it on your controllers/actions, and override `AuthorizeCore`. If you need custom logic to extract the username and password from the request, you can do that through setting the `User` property on `HttpContext` in an `OnAuthorization` override.

Comment: Thanks. The AuthorizeCore() method takes a HttpContext as its argument, which I don't really understand. This is a simple task but MVC is proving a nightmare for it.

Comment: It gets called on authorisation through MVC JuJu, so you have access to it there

Answer (score 0):

You should use a basic Web Application Template, it gives you controllers to edit users and use authentication. Then, you will be able to allow certain controllers, or certain action of controllers.
For a controller, you just have to put [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] tag just before the definition of the controller to just allow this action to Admin Roles.

Comment: My Application is nearly complete, I don't really want to do it again with a new template.

Comment: So please create custom membership provider. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655383/how-can-i-attach-a-custom-membership-provider-in-my-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score -1):

In your web.config add :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

And in your controller :

```
LoginUtility lu = new LoginUtility();
if(lu.Login("username", "password") == true){
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(...);
}
```